# Thread "blocks" or "stops" at a certain point in my code - Networking / Server

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

```
    public class ServerRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting...");
                Socket sock = socket.accept();
                System.out.println("Waiting... 2");
                ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                Object object = stream.readObject();
                System.out.println("Waiting... 3");
                if (object instanceof Client) {
                    Client c = (Client) object;
                    conns.put(c, sock);
                    System.out.println("Waiting... 4");
                    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                    oos.flush();
                    System.out.println("Waiting... 5");
                    output.put(sock, oos);
                    sendMessage(new Message("[" + c.getClientType() + "] " + c.getName() + " connected."));
                    System.out.println("Waiting... 6");
                    threads.put(c, new Thread(new ClientHandler(sock, c)));
                    threads.get(c).start();
                    System.out.println("Waiting... 7");
                    updateClientList();
                    System.out.println("Waiting... 8");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code stops at "Waiting... 6".. For some reason when I start the new thread, the current thread just stops. I have tried several variations but cannot figure it out - I think it is something simple that I have done wrong.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What does `ClientHandler` do in its constructor?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: I've just figured out that the code is stopping when the ClientHandler does this, oiStream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream()).

Comment: You probably want to move all networking code into the ClientHandler’s `run` method.

Comment: Okay VGR I will give it a go.